# Cherrypy running behind Apache windows

Tags: python, windows, apache, cherrypy

I'm trying to run my python application behind apache, to make it accessible from the internet. But I have to say I'm struggling a bit to make the whole thing work.
I have Apache 2 installed, not much configured as far as I know, don't really know where to start.

Here is the conf file of my python script:

```
[global]
server.socket_host= '127.0.0.1'
server.socket_port= 8080
server.thread_pool= 5
tools.sessions.on= True
tools.encode.encoding= 'Utf-8'
[/annexes]
tools.staticdir.on = True
tools.staticdir.dir = "my/path"
[/]
tools.proxy.on: True
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ProxyPass directive in your httpd.conf file to forward all requests at a virtual name to `http://YOUR.SERVER.com:8080</code>`.

Something like

`ProxyPass /myCherryPySite http://YOUR.SERVER.com:8080`

Make sure you also go through the documentation of Apache. You will need to enable mod_proxy for that. Other options are the URL rewriting engine of Apache, for which you will need complex regular expressions!

EDIT: Here the YOUR.SERVER.com is any server which is running your cherrypy site. It should be accessible from the server where apache is running (localhost in case it is the same server). Call it my.apace.com for example. For accessing the cherrypy site, you can simply say http://my.apache.com/myCherryPySite